# Can't edit css styles for :before, :after?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this styling:

```
section.tipos .content > div:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
    content: " ";
    height: 10px;
    left: 32%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Which works fine,

But when some events happen I would like to change the left property for a different %

I know this could be achieved (for sure) using classnames or styles. But my boss doesn't like much the class names unless they're 100% needed.

**Question is:** Can I alter the css for a pseudo selector from javascript? Something like this (but that works)

```
$('section.tipos .content > div:before').css({ 'left' : 50+index*17});
```

Comment: unfortunately you need a workaround for this, like appending a new `<style>` for the element and set `!important`

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are not available in any way to your Javascript code.

The best work-around you can hope for is to use your Javascript to change the class of the main element, and have separate CSS code for the `:before` pseudo-element depending on which class it has.

Then you could have CSS code like this:

```
section.tipos .content > div.newClass:before {
    ....
}
```

However, I note that you're wanting to set the width to a calculated value; that might be tricky using the above technique. [CSS `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) may help, depending what `index` is being used for, and depending what level of browser support you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending '%' to the css style value:

```
$('section.tipos .content > div:before').css({ 'left' : 50+index*17 + '%'});
```