# jQuery click + if + bind

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, click, bind

I am trying to show a tooltip if a searchfield got a empty value.
After the Tooltip is shown, i want to bind a click function to the body to hide the tooltip again. But for some reason after adding the bind command to the click function, the tooltip wont even appear. I already checked the console, but without any results.
Here is my Code:

```
$('#search_top .search_click').click(function() {
    if($('#search_top #suchfeld').val() == '') {
        $('.search_tooltip, .search_tooltip:after').css('display', 'block');
        $('.search_tooltip, .search_tooltip:after').addClass('active');
        $('body').bind('click', closeTip);
    }
    else {
        $('#search_top').submit();
    }
});


function closeTip() {
        $('.search_tooltip, .search_tooltip:after').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Don't forget to unbind the closeTip click handler in the closeTip function.

Comment: http://webdesignledger.com/tips/9-jquery-mistakes-you-shouldnt-commit 4) 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use this kind of code but seems to be what you are looking for:

```
$('#search_top .search_click').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($('#search_top #suchfeld').val() == '') {
        $('.search_tooltip').show().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#search_top').submit();
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('body').bind('click', closeTip);
});

function closeTip() {
        $('.search_tooltip').hide();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect thanks. What I dont get is, why is the function to bind the closeTip function triggering after the Tooltip is opened?

Comment: Because when clicking on .search_click event propagate to body and then closes the tooltip. That's why i use `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Dont know about this function, this is pretty cool, thanks a lot ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`:before` and `:after` (and other pseudo elements) are not accessible with Javascript. You should change the class of the parent object in the spirit of the following:

```
div:before {
  content: 'Lorem ipsum';
  display: none;
}

div.active:before {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You're sure about this? Cause my this worked without any problems:

        $('.search_tooltip, .search_tooltip:after').css('display', 'block');
        $('.search_tooltip, .search_tooltip:after').addClass('active');

Comment: There have been several questions about it already, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108475/cant-edit-css-styles-for-before-after)